# Web-based tool for testing FTP/HTTP server performance from various locations

Tags: network-speed

I would like to test the upload speed of my FTP/HTTP server against various international locations.
I could imagine that a web-based tool (like a reverse speedtest.net) for this exists, but when it does I can't find it...

I have a 100mb download available via FTP which I would like to have tested from various locations.

In the meantime it would be great if you could download the file for me and report which speeds you're getting:
`ftp://ftpuser:ftp.2013Test@185.2.103.166/100mb.test`

This file is hosted on a virtual private server and I'm only reaching about 10Mbit/s (1MB/s) when downloading it to my office location. The server is supposed to have a 100Mbit uplink and the hosting provider claim they cannot find any errors at their side. Running speedtest-cli on the server indeed reports an uplink speed of near 100Mbit/s.
I have a 120Mbit/s downlink connection (which I also achieve from various international locations), so why can't I get this near 100Mbit/s speed from my server??

Comment: Bandwidth delay product.

Comment: If the speed from the server to [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/) shows 100Mbps, and you're confident that your office connection isn't the limiting factor, it could be the software. What FTP package are you running? Can you achieve 100Mbps download from the server to any other site via FTP?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu server 13.10 and vsftpd with mostly default settings. The link i've pasted in my question was tested by the hosting provider and they claim they can achieve 100Mbit using 'an external connection outside their network'. I just realized I might as well upload FROM the server to somewhere to test the uplink, i'm looking for a public FTP server accepting uploads.